# RealmBaseAdapter with multiple RealmObjects

Tags: android, generics, realm

I created two RealmObjects:

> public class HashtagObject extends RealmObject
>
> public class SearchtagObject extends RealmObject

Then I want to use one adapter for two RealmObjects, I try to add RealmBaseAdapter with generic but it's not  correct:

```
public  class CustomListAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<T extends RealmObject> implements ListAdapter{

private final OrderedRealmCollection<T>  mItenName;
private Activity mContext;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, OrderedRealmCollection<T> realmResults){
    super(context, realmResults);
    this.mItenName=realmResults;
    this.mContext= context;
}}
```

How do I use one adapter with multiple RealmObjects?

Comment: That entirely depends on how you intend to show two completely different RealmObjects in the same `ListView`, considering afaik Realm [doesn't support generic RealmObjects](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2265), and currently you're only giving the adapter **one** result set, which can belong only to **one** RealmObject.

Comment: In your case, the solution is most definitely that these two RealmObjects should be one RealmObject.

Comment: My RealmObjects differ only one variable that is why it's not a problem to use onne adapter. But if I can't use RealmBaseAdapter with generic I  have only one way using two adapters? I  suppose it's not so good way

Comment: [Guide: Designing the Realm schema effectively](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/designing-the-schema-of-realm-effectively-and-other-realm-tips-feb76c5b6072#.fxmu0jq9u)  section `"I don’t really need polymorphism, I just need multiple classes that slightly differ from one another, but share some of the same elements”`. Merge your RealmObjects into one, and have a discriminator field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you shouldn't create two RealmObjects for this task. You should create one RealmObject.

```
public class HashtagObject extends RealmObject

public class SearchtagObject extends RealmObject
```

These should be

```
public class TagObject extends RealmObject {
    @Index
    private String type; //HASHTAG or SEARCHTAG
```

---

If you still need to show them separately, then you'll need two results, in which case you'll definitely need your custom adapter.

For this, I'd recommend somewhat mirroring what `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` does.

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    RealmResults<HashtagObject> hashtags;
    RealmResults<SearchtagObject> searchtags;

    Realm realm;

    RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Object element) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public SearchAdapter(Realm realm) {
        this.hashtags = realm.where(HashTagObject.class).findAllAsync();
        this.searchtags = realm.where(SearchtagObject.class).findAllAsync();

        this.hashtags.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        this.searchtags.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    private <T extends RealmModel> int getResultSize(RealmResults<T> results) {
        return ((results == null) || (!results.isValid()) || (results.isValid() && !results.isLoaded()) ? 0 : results.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1 /* header */ + getResultSize(hashtags) + 1 /* header */ + getResultSize(searchtags);
    }

    static final int HEADER = 0;
    static final int HASH = 1;
    static final int SEARCH = 2;

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position == 0 || position == 1 /*header*/ + getResultSize(hashtags)) {
            return HEADER;
        }
        if(position < 1 /*header*/ + getResultSize(hashtags)) {
            return HASH;
        }
        return SEARCH;
    }

    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == HEADER) {
            return new HeaderViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_header, parent, false));
        }
        if(viewType == HASH) {
            return new HashtagViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_hash, parent, false));
        }
        if(viewType == SEARCH) {
            return new SearchViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_search, parent, false));
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type [" + viewType + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder abstractHolder, int position) {
        if(abstractHolder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
            HeaderViewHolder holder = (HeaderViewHolder) abstractHolder;
            if(position == 0) {
                holder.setText(R.string.hash_header_text);
            } else {
                holder.setText(R.string.search_header_text);
            }
        } else if(abstractHolder instanceof HashtagViewHolder) {
            HashtagViewHolder holder = (HashtagViewHolder) abstractHolder;
            HashtagObject hashObject = hashtags.get(position - 1 /*header*/);
            holder.bind(hashObject);
        } else if(abstractHolder instanceof SearchViewHolder) {
            SearchViewHolder holder = (SearchViewHolder)abstractHolder;
            SearchtagObject searchObject = searchTags.get(
                 position - 1 /* header */ 
                          - 1 /* other header */ 
                          - getResultSize(hashtags) /* previous list */);
            holder.bind(searchObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But if i have two objects that are not associated with each other with different fields?  HashtagObject has hashtag field and SearchtagObject  has latitude and longtitude fields. I create TagObject with three fields. And  then I need to find all HashtagObject in TagObject. I have only hashtag field but latitude and longtitude fields will be null? As I understand @Index helps me with search but I have only one Object with a lot of empty fields?

Comment: Pretty much. Although technically it isn't impossible to show both types, you'd just have to write your adapter instead of `RealmBaseAdapter`. It depends on your design - are you supposed to show them all in one list, or separated from one another?

Comment: I need to show them separated from one to  another. At first, I  think to create two adapters it's simple way and very fast. But if  I will have three or  more RealmObjects don't  link with  each other it will be very bad decision. Another way I can use ArrayAdapter<String>   and constructor like:   'public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> hashtag, ArrayList<String> latitude, ArrayList<String> longtitude etc)' And translate all RealmObjects  to String. But it's not  good for perfomance.

Comment: I see. In that case, you'll have to make a custom adapter. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank  you for  your  help. It's  good  example, I have two question: 1) I can't find the method - holder.bind()? And HeaderViewHolder is  it for example or may be it's neсessary?

Comment: The bind method would be the view holder's method for its given type of object (`public void bind(Searchtagobject searchTag) {...}`) for example. I just skipped the view holders when writing this code, I focused on the adapter; the header just assumes you have a "header" of sorts to separate the two different types of objects you're showing

Comment: As I understand it, your example shows the different RealmObjects in one list, all right? An interesting example, take note! I need to display different RealmObjects in different lists using one adapter! I think that it will be easier, now try to create it! Thank you a lot for your time and effort!

Comment: `I need to display different RealmObjects in different lists using one adapter` Technically that's what I did in this example, I think