# How to replace RecyclerView.Adapter with RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` that uses eight different RealmObjects

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private String tag;
    private Realm realm;

    private RealmResults<HashtagObject> hashtags;
    private RealmResults<SearchtagObject> searchtags;
    etc.

   public SearchAdapter(Realm realm,final  String tag) {

        setHasStableIds(true);

        RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(Object element) {
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        this.realm=realm;
        this.tag=tag;
        this.hashtags = realm.where(HashtagObject.class).findAll();
        this.searchtags = realm.where(SearchtagObject.class).findAll();
        ...
        this.hashtags.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        this.searchtags.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        ...
   }
}
```

I am trying to create `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` constructor, but there is `OrderedRealmCollection` there. How to use `OrderedRealmCollection` for my scheme?

The second question it's a problem with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Every time when the Realm database changed, `onBindViewHolder` is activated. But I need this method to work only when the user interacts with the recyclerView, not permanently. And how `notifyDataSetChanged()` method works in `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`.

Comment: Hmm this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34976540/2413303 and eerily familiar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106423/realmbaseadapter-with-multiple-realmobjects but when I needed this I wrote my own adapter for the multiple datasets.

Comment: The second link was my question:) You gave a good example! I did it and everything works without problems. The only problem with constant triggering notifyDataSetChanged(); I wrote about it above. But i tnought the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter can help me optimaze my program. Sorry for a lot of questions, but I am trying to understand in detailed everithing about Realm database.I am happy to work with this database.

Comment: I've actually had to create a multi-type adapter before (couldn't solve it with single table inheritance), but it is super DIY.

Comment: I wrote about it in another topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297838/realm-transaction-using-from-different-thread. Can you explain the next question or may be where i can read about it  - At what moment does the database change? Realm.close or Realm.committransaction? (in non Looper thread) For example, If we have 2 threads - UI and background (non looper), from these threads we change the same element at the same time. How would this happen?

Comment: On Non-looper thread? With `beginTransaction()` or if `realm.refresh()` is called. Opening the first local Realm instance on a thread will also use the latest Realm version.